# Draw label outside polygon, if it not fit's inside (MultiPolygon, QGIS)

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling, callout

I would like to label polygons (parts of multipolygons) inside IF the label fits completely inside, else the label should be outside with a call out.
I tryed that, as you can see in the screenshot:
I was using a expression, to force the drawing of the label 4mm distance to anchor point if the area is smaller then 25ha. Works with #128 but not with #106 - so this solution is not working. (Even if that would work, it is not a good solution since it's scale depended!)

[image]

The task seems simple, but I found no solution: Draw label outside, if it not fit's inside. If it's outside, draw it with call out to the objects interior. (#128 is the expected result)

Answer (score 3):

The [Automatic placement of labels outside polygons](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-automatic-placement-of-labels-outside-polygons) is a new feature that was added in QGIS 3.14. It enables you to add labels outside the polygons automatically if they do not fit inside the polygon.

Here is the illustration from the link above:

[image]

Also, the new feature provides an option to place labels outside the polygons in case you choose other placement modes:

[image]

I think it is a great chance to try it.